# How to exchange AndroidTouch+Keyprocessor after 1.12 update(FlutterView deprecation)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, plugins, gamepad-api

I need [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/RainwayApp/flutter_gamepad/issues/3#issue-558180218) fixed, so I did some digging into the error myself. I am kind of stuck but here is what I've got:

After the Flutter 1.12 update, the API using [FlutterView](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/app/FlutterActivity.java) is now depracted and instead the new [embedding packages](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity.java) should be used. Mainly, platform specific java/android/kotlin code should talk to flutter via the [DartExecutor](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/dart/DartExecutor.html) or via callbacks from [method channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab). However I cannot find information on how to add new button calls with a dart plugin.

The way I understand [this code(also below)](https://github.com/RainwayApp/flutter_gamepad/blob/d2e703c9fc776ddfc6c6e782a59532bf18d878bb/android/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutter_gamepad/FlutterGamepadPlugin.kt#L68), the renderer Flutter uses is overridden by a very similar one, that adds the functions to handle button presses from the gamepad to the button press-handling of the original flutter renderer. However this won't work anymore beacuse the original FlutterView required for this is deprecated since 1.12 and is required to get the `view` and `{key|touch}ProcessorField` objects.

```
val view: FlutterView = registrar.view()

fun viewField(name: String): Field {
   val field = FlutterView::class.java.getDeclaredField(name)
   field.isAccessible = true
   return field
}

// Hack: swap in a new AndroidTouchProcessor.
val touchProcessorField = viewField("androidTouchProcessor")
val rendererField = viewField("flutterRenderer")
val renderer = rendererField.get(view) as FlutterRenderer
val touchProcessor = GamepadAndroidTouchProcessor(renderer)
touchProcessorField.set(view, touchProcessor)

// Hack: swap in a new AndroidKeyProcessor.
val keyProcessorField = viewField("androidKeyProcessor")
val keyEventChannelField = viewField("keyEventChannel")
val textInputPluginField = viewField("mTextInputPlugin")
val keyEventChannel = keyEventChannelField.get(view) as KeyEventChannel
val textInputPlugin = textInputPluginField.get(view) as TextInputPlugin
val keyProcessor = GamepadAndroidKeyProcessor(keyEventChannel, textInputPlugin)
keyProcessorField.set(view, keyProcessor)
```

How can integrating gamepad buttons be achieved after Flutter 1.12?